# plain continuous form of a verb vs appending ところ

Tags: word-choice, usage

plain continuous form of a verb vs appending ところ

What's the difference between the following 2 sentences:

> 今料理を作っているところだ

> 今料理を作っているんだ

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between the following 2 sentences:
>
> 今料理を作っているところだ

"Tokoro" here is something like "right in the middle of" in English. "I'm right in the middle of cooking", for example if you need to make an excuse to get off the phone.

> 今料理を作っているんだ

The basic meaning is the same but there is less emphasis on the immediacy of the action.